# Change assembly version for multiple projects

Tags: .net, assemblies, versioning

How can I change the assembly version in the file AssemblyInfo.cs for multiple projects. We have around 75 project in our solution and we need to change the version almost every week. What is the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I usually create a file called AssemblyVersionInfo.cs that is included *as a link* in all projects. I make this file contain the version attributes, and remove the same attributes from the regular AssemblyInfo.cs files. Then you can update version numbers in one file only, and make all the projects share the same number.

To add the file as a link; right click the project in the solution explorer, select "Add" -> "Existing item...". Browse to the file, and then click the little arrow in the right edge of the add button, and select "Add As Link" in the dropdown menu.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx

Comment: Very step by step: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328977/The-Right-Way-to-Version-Your-Assemblies

Answer (score 3):

I used find/replace function in VS.
e.g. replacig **`assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.`** to **`assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.`** in all solution did what I neded :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to have a master build script that uses the AssemblyInfo Task to set the version number at build time(http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers) and then define the versions numbers as properties in the msbuild script.